# Installing scoop fails: "Running the installer as administrator is disabled by default, see https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install#for-admin"

Tags: failed-installation, scoop-installer

Whenever i run the command line to install scoop on windows through Powershell, it just says "Running the installer as administrator is disabled by default, see https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install#for-admin for details."

I have tried to run Powershell as administrator and the "-RunAsAdmin" option but none seem to work for me.

Answer (score 21):

You need run the command as administrator. Try the below command:

```
iex "& {$(irm get.scoop.sh)} -RunAsAdmin"
```